# How to turn last name, name and second name into initials?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe with last name, name and second name:

```
name
Johnson John William
Peterson Andrew James
Burnham Edward Alexander
....
```

I want to create new column "initials" which will take only last name and add with underscore first letters of first and second names:

```
name                         initials
Johnson John William        Johnson_J_W
Peterson Andrew James       Peterson_A_J
Burnham Edward Alexander    Burnham_E_A
....
```

How could I do that in short way? I have idea of using split() and than create three columns, extracting first letters from two of them than joining all three again with underscores, but it seems inefficient

Comment: Not sure what could be more efficient than that, which seems to be the least amount of work you'd have to do. Preferably without the unnecessary intermediate columns.

Comment: I suggest that you solve a simpler version of the problem first. How would you do this for a single name?

Comment: Worrying about inefficient code that doesn't yet exist is a waste of time. Write something that works first, then evaluate its efficiency.

Comment: Do you know about `.apply`? If you have a function that transforms one of the values, you can tell Pandas to use it for the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can use a simple regex, you will benefit from a vectorized (i.e. fast) string operation:

```
df['initials'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'\s+([A-Z])[a-z]+', r'_\1', regex=True)
```

If the case doesn't matter:

```
df['initials'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'\s(\w)\w+', r'_\1', regex=True)
```

output:

```
                       name      initials
0      Johnson John William   Johnson_J_W
1     Peterson Andrew James  Peterson_A_J
2  Burnham Edward Alexander   Burnham_E_A
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas' [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method, passing a function (`to_initials`) that processes each entry in the `'name'` column of the dataframe.

```
def to_initials(x):
    last, first, second = x.split(" ")
    return last+"_"+first[0]+"_"+second[0]

df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["Johnson John William","Peterson Andrew James","Burnham Edward Alexander"]})

df["initials"] = df["name"].apply(to_initials)
```

or it's possible to use python's lambda functions and do it in one line.

```
df["initials"] = df["name"].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0]+"_"+x.split(" ")[1][0]+"_"+x.split(" ")[2][0])
```

If there are entries with only one name, you would have to extend this function though.